# Why am I getting the error mongo.db aggregate?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, nuxt.js

```
ids = 602bc4c1a7fe3222c48b4efc 
email = anartoflijkjk67g6@gmail.com
const Order = await User.aggregate([
  { $match: { email } },
  { $unwind: '$orders' },
  { $set: { _id : ids, "orders.orderStatus": "Paid" } }
])
```

I get an error while trying to update

```
code: 40324
codeName: "Location40324"
name: "MongoError"
ok: 0
```

My DB JSON

```
{                                                                                                                                                                                              14:46:51
  comments: [],
  orders: [
    {
      _id: 602bc4c1a7fe3222c48b4efc,
      shares: 111,
      userName: '111',
      orderCreationDate: 2021-02-16T13:12:33.176Z,
      orderStatus: 'In Cart',
      totalOrderValue: 555100
    },{
      _id: 0000000000000001,
      shares: 111,
      userName: '1112',
      orderCreationDate: 2021-02-16T13:12:33.176Z,
      orderStatus: 'In Cart',
      totalOrderValue: 55500
    }
  ],
  tikTokAccounts: [],
  tikTokVideos: [],
  paymentCards: [],
  _id: 602bc0e024e05b15ccb12bc6,
  userName: 'frfrf',
  email: 'anartoflijkjk67g6@gmail.com',
  password: '$2b$10$NC5CXa3lXK4Cl1.W3c3nae.YrJvvhum//YSYskXkKKiDULeJdvZoO',
  avatar: 'https://www.flaticon.com/svg/static/icons/svg/667/667378.svg',
  status: 'USER',
  moneyAmount: 0,
  __v: 2
}
```

How to find an order by id of a user with a specific email, and replace his orderStatus with "Paid"?
How can I fix it?
I kind of did as in the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have `orders._id`, with `update()` you can do what you want, so just try like this:

```
db.collection.update({
  "orders._id": "602bc4c1a7fe3222c48b4efc",
  "email": "anartoflijkjk67g6@gmail.com"
},
{
  $set: {
    "orders.$.totalOrderValue": 12345
  }
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/81qG4cWlCfc)